# Find not working with children().eq(n).nextAll().find('.class')

Tags: jquery

I want to get all next ('.slide') div from specified particular indexed div.
Below example i want all ('.slide') div after "C"

**HTML**

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div class='slide'>A</div>
    <div class='slide'>B</div>
    <div class='slide'>C</div>
    <div class='slide'>D</div>
    <div class='slide'>E</div>
    <div class='otherdiv'>F</div>
    <div class='otherdiv'>G</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:** **`$("#parent").children().eq(2).nextAll().find('.slide')`**

**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7masn3a9/1/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is currently doing the following:

```
//Retrieves the DOM element <div class='slide'>C</div>
$("#parent").children().eq(2)

//Retrieves DOM elements for spans D-G
.nextAll();

//Looks *inside* spans D-G for inner elements that have class 'slide'
.find('.slide')
```

[.nextAll](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/) supports a selector to filter:

```
$("#parent").children().eq(2).nextAll('.slide');
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method only searches children elements, not siblings. If you use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), your code should work.

```
$("#parent").children().eq(2).nextAll().filter('.slide')
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7masn3a9/2/)

Alternatively you can include your selector in the call to [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

```
$("#parent").children().eq(2).nextAll('.slide')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find next by a specific value like C :

```
$("#parent").filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() == "C"
}).nextAll(".slide");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#parent").children().eq(2).nextAll('.slide')
```

Answer (score -1):

you want `.filter('.slide')`,

because `.find()` looks down the tree but you already have the divs.

Edit: also `$("#parent > div.slide:gt(2)")` would do the same by selector only